# how to monkey patch an ambient module in node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, monkeypatching

I have installed mocha globally and use it to run some tests:

```
$> mocha test.js
```

In the root of test.js file I want to monkey patch mocha:

```
require('mocha').Runner.prototype.runTests = function() {...}
```

however require('mocha') fails since mocha is not in node_modules but installed globally.

If I install mocha locally in my project then require('mocha') finds it but it is not the same module as the ambient one used for execution so the patch is not good.

If I run mocha from the local repository rather than the global one then everything works fine:

```
$> ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test.js
```

however I want to run mocha from the global repository. any idea?

EDIT: I gave up on the attempt to access the global mocha module and it seems runing mocha locally and requiring it locally is good enough for [my use case](https://github.com/yaronn/test-creep).

Comment: Please read http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/ and http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/04/06/npm-1-0-link/ . Also, what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: `require('mocha')` if mocha is loaded globally works.  Is mocha onbly installed as a dependency?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm familiar with these posts. I'm t trying to tell mocha not to run some tests. but I have my own logic to do it so this needs to be intrusive. however I try to avoid changing mocha code directly so I can get future versions of it.

Comment: @PascalBelloncle create the simplest p.js file with just require('mocha'). then if mocha is not installed locally calling mocha p will result in error that mocha is not found.mocha is not in

Comment: yeah, it helps if I don't try this from somewhere where `mocha` is already installed locally.  Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Is using `npm link mocha` an option?  This should work.

Comment: I prefer not to do it. Since mocha is already in memory I hope to get it directly. Besides the overhead (my users will need to do it to each of their project) I'm not sure if npm link is cross platform which is a requirement for me (not sure sym links work that well on windoes)

Answer (score 0):

Given that `npm root -g` tells you the directory where all global node modules are installed (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules` on my machine) and you can pass an absolute path to `require`, it is possible to do this:

```
var mocha = require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha");
```

This loads the global installation of mocha.